# How can i defined attributes for products which is already inside the website

Tags: magento-1.9, import

How can i defined attributes for the products which is already inside available in my website and also how to the removed duplicate products.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes in magento admin panel itself for products. Then set the values for the attribute using the following code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$product->setAttributeName('123');
$product->save();
```

If you listed the duplicate product means you can use it productid or sku to delete it by the following code

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load( $productId )->delete(); 
Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)->delete();
```

To run php file root directory you need to add these lines

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

Example code:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Now you can run ANY Magento code you want

// Change 12 to the ID of the product you want to load
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12);

echo $_product->getName();
```

Comment: where i can use these codes.

Comment: If you have the custom module means you can run in it controller page or else you can place a php file in root directory with this code and run it in url.
But to run in root directory you need to extend the Mage.php in the file.

I have edited the answer with the Mage.php included

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get you.

Comment: You can run the example code in your site url. lIke www.magento.com/test.php. You need to upload the code in root directory.

Comment: Please forgive me, i  couldn't get you. Again you willing to answer my question, pls suggested screen shot or video demo(If You Willing).

Comment: refer this http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/

Comment: do u know how to add sample track list for songs related product

Comment: Didn't get you clearly. You need to add related product?

Comment: How can i add sample track list, like this

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b0gqj2

Comment: track list for products?

Comment: yes, like albums

Comment: did you get, what i try to telling you,

Comment: yes. But you can add a sample video or song to the produtc description or through custom attribute. But add a track of songs is not possible

Comment: Is possible can i add all sample tracks via description,

Comment: yes. i think so

Comment: how to add audio link via description

Comment: refer here - http://www.human-element.com/magento-jplayer-play-nice-together/